# Is there a way to guage when a 2015 Honda Civic reaches its normal coolant operating temperature?

Tags: honda, civic, coolant, gauges, instrument-cluster

Just bought a 2015 Honda Civic and then noticed that the coolant temperature gauge is not in the instrument panel. There are only two instrument cluster panel idiot lights dedicated to coolant over or under temperature.

Comment: In absense of a built in temperature gauge you can use an ODB reader or an aftermarket sensor.

Answer (score 1):

An OBDII display is your best bet. There are lots available similar to this. 
[image]

Comment: wow. uh – maybe a link would be sufficient?